# Why am I getting a Thread 1: fatal error in this function

Tags: swift, function, skaction

I am getting the following error on the line `basicTop.run(SK...`

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I do not know why I am getting this. I get this error message when I click on the simulator screen.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var brickSwitch: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicTop: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicBottom: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicLeft: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicRight: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        layoutScene()
    }

    func turnBasicTop() {
        basicTop.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        turnBasicTop()
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether an optional `basicTop` contains a value,

```
if basicTop != nil {
    basicTop.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
}
```

Also, please try to read articles before posting basic questions

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Comment: I changed it to that:   func turnBasicTop() {
            if basicTop != nil {
                basicTop.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
            }
        }                                                                                                                                       The error went away, but when I click on the simulator screen nothing happens.

Comment: this is because the object 'basicTop' doesn't have any value. You have to assign value to basicTop.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to set var BasicTop equal to an image? If so, how do I do that? I am new to programming, so I am sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    var brickSwitch: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side");
    var basicBottom: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicLeft: SKSpriteNode!
    var basicRight: SKSpriteNode!
    
    
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
layoutScene()
        
    }       Should all the variables be written like var basicTop

Comment: I changed func turnBasicTop() back to how it was originally, and I am not getting any errors. When I load the simulator, however, the image still doesn't rotate.

Comment: You don’t need that `if` statement. Simply: `basicTop?.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))`

Comment: @Rob it says Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'SKSpriteNode'

Comment: You declared your property as `var basicTop: SKSpriteNode!`, which is an optional, specifically an implicitly unwrapped optional (IOP). If it's saying that “Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value” then the code isn't as you’ve outlined in your question (e.g. you must have unwrapped it already).

Comment: Right now, it is set as var basicTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side"); However, the image still does not rotate.